# Access variable outside of function in javascript

Tags: ajax, json, forms, function, variables

I have a small javascript function to validate my form on submit.

With that i do some basic validation to check things are not empty. There is a also an ajax/json request that returns either a 1 or 0 if a person is over 18 or not.

all works fine except the json part will not return valid to the rest of the script, its just local to that part and for the life of me i cannot figure out how to get it to work.

```
function validate_form() {

    valid = true;

    //Set varialbles
    var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
    var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var comments = $('#comments').val();
    var day = $('#day').val();
    var month = $('#month').val();
    var year = $('#year').val();


    if ($('[name=photo]').val() == "") {
        $('#formtext1').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $('#formtext2').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        });
        valid = false;
    }

    //check that terms have been accepted
    if (myForm.terms.checked == false) {
        $('#formtext1').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $('#formtext2').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        });
        valid = false;
    }


    if (firstname != "" && lastname != "" && email != "" && comments != "" && day != "" && month != "" && year != "") {} else {
        $('#formtext1').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $('#formtext2').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        });
        valid = false;
    }

    $.getJSON('mydomainhere.com/dob_validate/' + day + '/' + month + '/' + year, function(result) {    
        //Check dob
        var age = result.age

        if (age) {
            //Do nothing
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
    });
    return valid;
}​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `var valid=true;` at the top (or outside to make it global) of your function.  It looks like you are creating a local variable when you get the result back which goes out of scope after that code block.

To make it async from my comment:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'mydomainhere.com/dob_validate/',
 dataType: 'json',
 async: false,
 data: day + '/' + month + '/' + year,
 success: 
      function(result) {
          var age = result.age 
          if (age) { } 
          else {
           valid = false;
          }
     }
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: ok, ive updated that and its made a difference. But yeh you're right, it appears its a local variable when i get the result back which I cannot make a global varialbe no matter what ive tried.

Comment: You can set it outside the function to make it global for the entirely script.

Comment: yeh but how can i update it with the result i get back from json?

Comment: Exactly in the same way.  Assign it directly (valid = true) or valid = result.IsValid (or whatever you are sending back from the server)

Comment: i have set it like valid = false but then at the end of the script when do return valid, it ignores what ever i set in the json part.

Comment: What is age returning? Try alerting it and rather than doing if (age) do if (age == 1) { } else if (age == 0) { valid = false; }

Comment: thanks, that did nothing either. I really can't see why this doesnt work.

Comment: 1 if they over 18 and 0 if they are not. that part does work fine. if i alert from within that function its all good. just cannot get it working outside of that.

Comment: it feels like the json is excuting after the rest of the script.

Comment: You can set the async option to false if you use the $.ajax function

Comment: that hasn't worked either. its returning a value fine which makes me think that part works. I just need to use that reponse and if 0 dont let the form submit. i cant believe its this diffiuclt

Comment: Try using: window.valid rather than valid.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of asynchronous callbacks!

The main problem I see here, is that you're using `$.getJSON`, and expecting it to be executed inline.  The way your function is written in the question, the statement

```
return valid;
```

will be executed **before** the result function of the `$.getJSON` (the following statements):

```
//Check dob
var age = result.age

if (age) {
    //Do nothing
} else {
    valid = false;
}
```

If you want the `return` statement to be executed *after* you get the result of the AJAX call, you’ll have to make the AJAX call **synchronous**, not *asynchronous*.  Darren's answer shows you how to do that.

A second problem with the function as it’s written in the question, is that `valid` is assigned `true` at the start of your function, then it’s assigned `false` several times, but it never receives the value of `true` again!  Is this your actual code?  If not, could you please edit your question, and adjust it to match your actual code?

Comment: Have you read the below discussion? He mentioned that he has changed it to synchronous. And you are thinking wrongly, once one field gets wrong, then what is the point of having the form as a valid one?

Answer (score 0):

From the above discussion, i assume that you have changed the option `async:false`, otherwise there will be another case should be taken to consideration.

I suspect,
The returned type of the age is string, then let's say

```
var age = '0';

age == 0; // will be evaluated as true,
          // because it only looks for same value by converting to same type
```

Since the returned `age` is string(my assumption) the `else` part of your code never be executed. Because the if condition will evaluate a non empty string as true.

The following values will be evaluated as false, while all others will evaluate to true

- 0 or -0 (Most floating-point implementations have positive and
  negative zero, due to the IEEE 754 standard)
- null
- undefined
- NaN
- The empty string (“”)
- `false` itself

Therefore you have to check the type too,

use `age !== 0` instead within the if condition.

For more information [Rare Javascript Operators](http://timmywillison.com/pres/operators/#equality)